# Issue with sending $_SESSION with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that updates a row in a table, the query works when I hard coded the email value, but when I want to send the value as `$_SESSION` nothing happens in the row, and I won't get any errors either.

My working query is:

```
function profile_name($profile_name){
    $profile_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($profile_name)); 
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_name = '{$profile_name}' WHERE user_email = 'my@email.com' ");
}
```

When I send the `my@email.com` as session with the following code:

```
(isset($_POST['profile'], $_POST["{$_SESSION['email']}"])){ } 
 function profile_name($profile_name, $email){
    $profile_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($profile_name)); 
        mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_name = '{$profile_name}' WHERE user_email = '{$email}' ");
    }
```

nothing happens.

If I echo out the session `$_SESSION['email']` it prints `my@email.com`

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: Is your function even getting called? Did you check? What does session have anything to do with MySQL?

Comment: @maksimov Yes the function is working if i write it like this.

function profile_name($profile_name, $email){
 $profile_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($profile_name)); 
 mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_name = '{$profile_name}' WHERE user_email = 'my@email' ");
}

It update my user_name row. but not when im sending it with $_session

Comment: @Dymond, I don't understand what you mean when you say "when im sending it with $_session". Can you please elaborate? Preferably through adding more information to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still trying to understand what you mean by "sending the $_SESSION", but this statement looks weird:

```
$_POST["{$_SESSION['email']}"]
```

What it does is it's getting a value from `$_SESSION` array with the key `email`, and then uses this value as a key to `$_POST` array.

Assuming your `$_SESSION['email']` is set to `myemail@hotmail.com`, it would expect `$_POST['myemail@hotmail.com']` to return a value. For that your form would have to have an input control with name `myemail@hotmail.com`.

Since it is a very irregular way of doing things, I assume it might be a problem, unless it's a typo in your question.

What you probably meant to do is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['profile'], $_SESSION['email'])) {...
```

Comment: well yes, that is what I'm trying to do. but it still gives me nothing, nor an error or an input. But I will do as some people suggestion here and start over with mysqlli.

Comment: "Nothing" == your record isn't getting updated? I've asked you before, are you sure you are entering your function even? If it was a problem with MySQL it would have printed something in your error.log at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I think both columns are not integers, SO the values should be wrap with single quotes,

```
UPDATE user SET user_name = '{$profile_name}' WHERE user_email = '{$email}'
```

I'll suggest that you switch on using `PDO` or `MySQLi`.